# Firefox extension: how to get document of currently opened tab from popup.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have tried:

```
browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, callback)  // can't get extract document from tab
browser.windows.getCurrent()  // can't get document from window
content.document  // document of popup
```

I need document to get selected text on currently opened site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need `activeTab` permission and `executeScript` function:

```
browser.tabs
      .executeScript({
        code: "document.getSelection().toString()"
      })
      .then(results => {
        console.log(results[0])
      });
```